# Есть большой класс, можно ли его разделить на много мелких

Tags: java, рефакторинг

Имеется проект в один класс, где есть абсолютно все, что мне было нужно до этого момента, но сейчас нужно расширить функционал в сторону поддержки других осей и исправления косяка с winxp. Пока не понял точно в чем косяк, но этот рефакторинг должен облегчить внедрение заплатки на этот косяк да и само расширение функционала, которое сейчас невозможно ибо это будет пирамида из фекалий.

Размер класса где-то 460 строк, вместе с документацией. Есть ли резон разделить на много небольших классов, а именно константы затолкать в отдельный [enum](/questions/tagged/enum).

Константы отвечают за путь к файлу и являются строками так, что по идее они и так константы, я разве что для проформы оформил, как константы и вынес в общий scope класса.

Остальные методы по назначению рассовать в разные классы и сделать разные методы под каждую платформу ([windows](/questions/tagged/windows), [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), [mac](/questions/tagged/mac)), как для самого функционала, так и для запуска через `main()`, то есть например метод `startWin ()` или `startMac ()` или как-то так.

А в `main()` оставить только проверку оси через `System.getPropierty("os.name");` (вроде бы так) и на основе этого, через if-else или switch или через перезагрузку метода start сделать метод `main ()` чистым и простеньким и изолировать от функционала.

Это просто небольшая утилита, которую разносит как дирижабль и боюсь 460 строк это еще только начало.

У меня штук 10 методов записывают в файл и это только пока, в остальных операционках будет так же, вопрос вот в чем, лучше всего оставить ибо работает или же переделать метод, чтобы он возвращал строку потом лепить через конкатенацию или `StringBuilder` или еще через что и записывать 1 раз, к слову читает тоже раз 9-10 с файлов?

Технически я бы лучше оставил, как есть в плане функционала иначе будет такая каша, что там не только топор, но еще и старые покрышки, носок, противогаз и целый атомный ледокол будет. Если обобщать, то вот 2 основных момента:

1. Лучше ли поделить программу на небольшие классы и [enum](/questions/tagged/enum)'ы (для других осей придется клепать еще [enum](/questions/tagged/enum)'ы потому что пути различаются), что значительно упростит ее переваривание и возможности к расширению.
2. нужно ли переделывать функционал в угоду уменьшению количества операций чтения-записи, если уже вроде как работает. Прошу сильно не пинать, это мой второй вопрос здесь и мой первый проект в принципе причем самостоятельный.

Comment: ,..на Ваш вопрос можно ответить просто - `да`... если Вы хотите чего то конкретного, то лучше приложить код...ну а из общих советов - ботайте паттерны и анти-паттерны, ботайте методы рефакторинга

Comment: Запихнув все в один класс, вы лишили себя преимуществ объектного программирования и как результат, столкнулись с проблемой масштабирования. Посмотрите паттерн MVC.

Comment: Кода слишком много было бы меня бы запинали именно за объем, хотя и так дофига написал. Именно те ответы которые мне были нужны. спасибо вам обоим. Я и не искал прямо такого ответа, как сделай так-то так-то, а потом вот так, а потом вот еще вот прямо так. Почитаю паттерны и рефакторинг и MVC. Спасибо вопрос считаю решенным.